# HTML td background image not displaying

Tags: html, css

I have my table with `<td>`s. This `<td>` contains a background element which is not displaying.

Below is my HTML table.

```
<div class="left">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">     
        <td class="displayroundtable"></td> <!-- for displaying background image -->
        <td><img src="<?php echo $this->static_address;?>images/MAX-RATING-100.jpg"></td>
    </table>
```

In the CSS,

```
.displayroundtable{
    background-image:url('<?php echo $this->static_address;?>images/2321.png');
}
```

I don't know why my background image never gets displayed?

Comment: could you post the whole code? It's not clear at all :)

Comment: Does your `.displayroundtable` element have a width? Use your browser's element inspector (F12 in most cases) to examine the dimensions of this element.

Comment: you are missing a / i think, before images

Comment: use inspector to see the url used

Comment: Look at the *html* output, verify the path is correct. You should also add `<tr>`s.

Comment: try putting some `width="50%"` etc. on those two `td`'s. missing `tr`'s in the html as well.

Comment: is the css created by php or just a css stylesheet?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is a width set on your empty cell, or else it will end-up at 0px thus not displaying anything. Also make sure that the browser renders the empty cells using the CSS rule `empty-cells:show` on the table.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_empty-cells.asp

The table needs TR to be standard compliant. I don't think it is the reason why your background is not displaying but make sure you surround your lines between `<tr>` .